Prevent Django DetailView from adding template context with name of object
I have a DetailView for users, and it seems to be adding a user context variable. This is problematic because I have an application-wide context variable, user that contains the current user that is being overridden. How can I prevent the DetailView from adding this context variable?

Override the get_context_data method in your DetailView and remove or modify the user variable from the context
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        # remove the 'user' context variable if it exists OR
        if 'user' in context:
            del context['user']
        # alternatively, you could update it to use your own user context variable
        # context['user'] = self.request.user
        
        return context


Do you know why it’s adding it? I don’t see it documented anywhere.
